# Drawing a non-regular shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following non regular shape, that is, a polygon within another polygon and two curved lines:

[image]

How can I draw it easily? I want to have also the coordinate of the vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.- Define some coordinates.

2.- Draw the polygon and define second polygon coordinates.

3.- Draw curved lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Point 1
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,3);
\coordinate (C) at (5,3);
\coordinate (D) at (4,-2);
\coordinate (E) at (0.5,-1);

%Point 2
\draw (A)-- coordinate[pos=.6] (AB) (B)--(C)
         --coordinate[pos=.45] (CD) (D)
         --coordinate[pos=.55] (DE) (E)
         --coordinate[pos=.55] (EA) cycle;

%Point 3
\draw (AB)--(CD)--(DE)--(EA)--cycle;
\draw (AB) to [out=60,in=120] (CD);
\draw (CD) to [out=-100,in=10] (DE);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]