# Drawing a polygon and using a third dimension to define the color

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polygon

I would like to draw a polygon, with a non-regular shape, providing coordinates x and y. I know how to do it, e.g., by using the answer provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306616/drawing-a-non-regular-shape). However, I would like to use the third dimension, let us call as z, that define the color inside of the polygon, using interpolation as needed.

For instance, an example of an image that I would like to create is the following:

[image: Polygon with gradient]

As you can see, a gradient would be formed, interpolating the values z as needed and using as a basis the existing values. For instance, the z value would be between 0 and 1, where 1 means black, 0 means white, and a value in ]0, 1[ means a gray scale that has a darker color for higher values. It is similar to density maps.

Edit 1:

This is my initial code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm]
\addplot[mark=*,patch,
colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (white);color(1cm) = (black)}, mesh/cols=50, z buffer=sort, restrict z to domain=0:inf, shader=faceted interp] 
table {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My data.txt is:

```
2.17    0.001   0.82044815
2.17    0.002   0.82345825
2.17    0.004   0.82679255
2.17    0.008   0.83334715
2.17    0.016   0.84395915
2.17    0.032   0.8584953
2.21    0.001   0.77582165
2.21    0.003   0.78520505
2.21    0.009   0.80205985
2.21    0.027   0.83085105
2.24    0.001   0.7227885
2.24    0.002   0.73391615
2.24    0.005   0.7543979
2.24    0.015   0.78798745
2.24    0.003   0.74176635
2.24    0.009   0.77064805
2.24    0.027   0.81042375
2.26    0.001   0.66545585
2.26    0.003   0.7012046
2.26    0.005   0.721067
2.26    0.009   0.7447984
2.26    0.015   0.76715245
2.26    0.027   0.794177
2.27    0.001   0.62916195
2.27    0.003   0.6774642
2.27    0.009   0.72961785
2.27    0.027   0.7861086
2.28    0.001   0.5750828
2.28    0.003   0.65059675
2.28    0.005   0.6802631
2.28    0.009   0.7145367
2.28    0.015   0.74447695
2.28    0.027   0.7774403
2.29    0.001   0.51357255
2.29    0.002   0.581053
2.29    0.003   0.6173075
2.29    0.009   0.6972096
2.29    0.027   0.76793225
2.31    0.001   0.36997965
2.31    0.002   0.474415
2.31    0.003   0.53649295
2.31    0.009   0.6587164
2.31    0.016   0.70870255
2.31    0.027   0.7482423
2.31    0.05    0.7912395
2.34    0.001   0.2204104
2.34    0.002   0.316308
2.34    0.003   0.39256745
2.34    0.004   0.45240835
2.34    0.009   0.5883453
2.34    0.016   0.6590771
2.34    0.027   0.71444205
2.34    0.05    0.7690014
2.38    0.001   0.13286995
2.38    0.002   0.1828288
2.38    0.004   0.2980268
2.38    0.008   0.4507145
2.38    0.016   0.58417075
2.38    0.032   0.6833616
```

The obtained result:

[image: obtained result of the code above]

However, the produced result is too far away to what I want. That is, the external/boundary points of the image should be linked by using curved lines and the interior points should be used to indicate the color of the polygon in a grayscale way...

Comment: See pages 162-168 of pgfplots manual.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have read these pages. I tried to use the contour filled, but without success when I tried to employ my data.txt file. It gives the following compilation error Package pgfplots Error: CRITICAL: shader=interp: got unsupported pdf shading type '0'. This may corrupt your pdf!. \end{axis}

Comment: Okay, the example on page 144 seems closer to what you want: color mesh instead of contours.