# Drawing irregular polygon around flow chart nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, flow-charts

Could I please get some help on drawing an irregular polygon around flow chart nodes. I saw a manual way of [drawing the polygons using a coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306616/drawing-a-non-regular-shape) but this is a bit impractical with flowcharts.

I would like 6 sided polygons as shown in the picture please. Is there a way without manually typing coordinates?

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass [12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, 
arrows, fit,
positioning,
backgrounds}
% \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}



\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,text width=5cm, draw=black]



\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5cm, draw=black, fill=none]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,text width=3cm, draw=black]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


\begin{document}


\begin{figure} 
 %  \resizebox{<horizontal size>}{<vertical size>}{%        
\centering
\resizebox{18 cm}{!}{%


\begin{tikzpicture}[ >=latex,auto]


% all nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below = of start] {Preprocessor Input: \\ A \\ B \\ C \\ D};

\node (pro1) [process, below  = of in1] {Process 1};

\node (pro2) [process, below = of  pro1] {Process 2};

\node (pro3)[process, below = of pro2] {Calculate: \\  From Variables A and B};

\node (dec1) [decision, below = of pro3] {X or\\ Y?};

\node (pro4)[process, below = of dec1, xshift = 5 cm] {Apply Y loads: \\  Apply $\lambda$ function  };

\node (pro4a)[process, below = of dec1, xshift = -5 cm] {Apply X loads:\\ Apply $\gamma$ function};

\node (pro5) [process, below =  of pro4] {Calculate: \\  U function   };

\node (pro5a) [process, below =  of pro4a] {Calculate: \\  U$_o$ function  };

\node (dec2) [decision, below = of pro5] {No. of desired \\ cycles reached?};

\node (dec2a) [decision, below = of pro5a] {No. of desired \\ cycles reached?};

\node (pro6) [process, below =of dec2a, xshift = 5cm, yshift = -1cm ] {Post-process in :  \\ Python};

\node (pro7)[process, left = of  dec1, xshift=19cm] {Reanalyse \\ Type 1};

\node (pro7a)[process, left = of  dec1, xshift=-7cm] {Reanalyse \\ Type 2};

\node (stop) [startstop,  below =of pro6] {End};

 
 \scoped[on background layer] {\node[regular polygon, draw, regular polygon sides = 4, dashed, fit=(pro4) (pro5)(dec2)(pro7) , fill = olive!25] {};} % using regular polygon
 
\node[left = of dec2, xshift = -10 cm, yshift =  5 cm, fill = olive!80]  {Type 2 System}; 

 \scoped[on background layer] {\node[draw, dashed, fit=(pro4a) (pro5a)(dec2a)(pro7a), fill = olive!25] {};} %using just draw command 
 
\node[right = of dec2a, xshift = 10 cm, yshift =  5 cm, fill = olive!80]  {Type 1 System}; 

%arrows 

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
\draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (pro5);
\draw [arrow] (pro6)--(stop);
\draw [arrow]  (pro7)  |-  (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro7a) |- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro4a) -- (pro5a);
\draw [arrow] (pro5a) -- (dec2a);
\draw [arrow] (pro5) -- (dec2);
\draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[anchor=west] {No } (pro7);
\draw [arrow] (dec2)|- node[anchor=north] {\qquad Yes} (pro6);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -| node[anchor=east] {X} (pro4a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -| node[anchor=west] {Y} (pro4);
\draw [arrow] (dec2a) -| node[anchor=east] {No } (pro7a);
\draw [arrow] (dec2a)|- node[anchor=north] {\qquad Yes} (pro6);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
 
        \caption{Caption for flowchart }
        \label{flowchart}
      
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your irregular polygon you need to draw as path around selected nodes: `\draw (<coordinate 1>)  -|  (<coordinate 2>)  -|  (<coordinate 3>) -| (cycle);`, Conclusion: there is no other way.

Comment: BTW, also with using `fit` library you need to define coordinates which is inside node. In your case, you can stick with such solution, if you rearrange your flowchart (move side branches more apart).

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. I was going to go with specifying exact coordinates but John's method with `path` seems a better choice

Comment: Sorry, but you go with solution which I propose in my comment and was spelled out out by @John Kormylo's answer. If this is better choice is matter of personal preference. Anyway, so far you not accept any od received answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is similar to fitting.  First you identify the corners, connect them using right angles then add offsets.  I put the labels at the centers of the local bounding boxes (more or less).

\documentclass [12pt]{article}

```
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, 
arrows, fit, calc,
positioning,
backgrounds}
% \usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}



\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,text width=5cm, draw=black]



\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=5cm, draw=black, fill=none]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,text width=3cm, draw=black]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


\begin{document}


\begin{figure} 
 %  \resizebox{<horizontal size>}{<vertical size>}{%        
\centering
\resizebox{18 cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[ >=latex,auto]

% all nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below = of start] {Preprocessor Input: \\ A \\ B \\ C \\ D};

\node (pro1) [process, below  = of in1] {Process 1};

\node (pro2) [process, below = of  pro1] {Process 2};

\node (pro3)[process, below = of pro2] {Calculate: \\  From Variables A and B};

\node (dec1) [decision, below = of pro3] {X or\\ Y?};

\node (pro4)[process, below = of dec1, xshift = 5 cm] {Apply Y loads: \\  Apply $\lambda$ function  };

\node (pro4a)[process, below = of dec1, xshift = -5 cm] {Apply X loads:\\ Apply $\gamma$ function};

\node (pro5) [process, below =  of pro4] {Calculate: \\  U function   };

\node (pro5a) [process, below =  of pro4a] {Calculate: \\  U$_o$ function  };

\node (dec2) [decision, below = of pro5] {No. of desired \\ cycles reached?};

\node (dec2a) [decision, below = of pro5a] {No. of desired \\ cycles reached?};

\node (pro6) [process, below =of dec2a, xshift = 5cm, yshift = -1cm ] {Post-process in :  \\ Python};

\node (pro7)[process, left = of  dec1, xshift=19cm] {Reanalyse \\ Type 1};

\node (pro7a)[process, left = of  dec1, xshift=-7cm] {Reanalyse \\ Type 2};

\node (stop) [startstop,  below =of pro6] {End};
 
\begin{scope}[on background layer, local bounding box=T1] 
  \path[draw, dashed, fill = olive!25]
    ($(pro4.north west)+(-1em,1em)$) |- ($(dec2.south)+(0,-1em)$) -| ($(pro7.north east)+(1em,1em)$)
    -- ($(pro7.north west)+(-1em,1em)$) |- cycle;
\end{scope}
 
\node[xshift=2em, fill = olive!80] at (T1.center) {Type 1 System}; 

\begin{scope}[on background layer, local bounding box=T2] 
  \path[draw, dashed, fill = olive!25]
    ($(pro7a.north west)+(-1em,1em)$) |-  ($(dec2a.south)+(0,-1em)$) -| ($(pro4a.north east)+(1em,1em)$)
    -| ($(pro7a.north east)+(1em,1em)$) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\node[xshift=-2em, fill = olive!80] at (T2.center) {Type 2 System}; 

%arrows 

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
\draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (pro5);
\draw [arrow] (pro6)--(stop);
\draw [arrow]  (pro7)  |-  (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro7a) |- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro4a) -- (pro5a);
\draw [arrow] (pro5a) -- (dec2a);
\draw [arrow] (pro5) -- (dec2);
\draw [arrow] (dec2) -| node[anchor=west] {No } (pro7);
\draw [arrow] (dec2)|- node[anchor=north] {\qquad Yes} (pro6);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -| node[anchor=east] {X} (pro4a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -| node[anchor=west] {Y} (pro4);
\draw [arrow] (dec2a) -| node[anchor=east] {No } (pro7a);
\draw [arrow] (dec2a)|- node[anchor=north] {\qquad Yes} (pro6);

\end{tikzpicture}
}% resizebox
        \caption{Caption for flowchart }
        \label{flowchart}
      
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you - That is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution where is rewritten your diagram code by using `chains` library for positioning of nodes and for the most of their connection drawn by `join` macro, used recent syntax for defining nodes styles and rearranged nodes positions so that you can use `fit`  (since you asking how to avoid to determines coordinates for them)  library which not require to determine coordinates of your irregular shape.

By aforementioned changes resulting code is much concise in comparison to yours:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{FlowChart/.style={
suspend join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}},
startstop/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=red!30,
                    minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm},
  process/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, fill=orange!30,
                    text width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
 decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.3, draw, fill=green!30,
                    minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
       io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                    draw, fill=blue!30,
                    minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
                    text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                    align=center,
                    },
    arrow/.style = {thick,-Triangle}
                        }   
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
  start chain = A going below,
   FIT/.style = {draw, dashed, fill = olive!25, 
                 inner sep=2mm, fit=#1}
                        ]
% nodes, 
% top branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arrow}] 
\node   [startstop] {Start};        % A-1
\node   [io]        {Preprocessor Input:\\ A\\ B\\ C\\ D};
\node   [process]   {Process 1};    %  A-3
\node   [process]   {Process 2};
\node   [process]   {Calculate:\\  From Variables A and B};
\node   [decision]  {X or Y?};      % A-6
% left branch    
\node   [process,   % A-7
         suspend join,
         below left= of A-6] {Apply X loads:\\ Apply $\gamma$ function};
\node   [process] {Calculate: \\  U$_o$ function}; 
\node   [decision]  {No. of desired \\ cycles reached?};    % A-9
% right branch
\node   [process,   % A-10
         suspend join,
         below right=of A-6] {Apply Y loads:\\  Apply $\lambda$ function  }; %A-9
\node   [process]   {Calculate: \\  U function};
\node   [decision] {No. of desired \\ cycles reached?};
\node   [process,   % A-13 
         suspend join,
         below=of A-9.south -| A-1] {Post-process in:  \\ Python};
\node   [startstop] {End};
    \end{scope}
%
\node (L)   [process,
             left =of A-6 -| A-7] {Reanalyse\\ Type 2};
\node (R)   [process, right=of A-6 -| A-10] {Reanalyse \\ Type 1};
% fit
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node[FIT=(R) (A-11) (A-12),
          label=\textbf{Type 1 System}] {};
\scoped[on background layer] 
    \node[FIT=(L) (A-8) (A-9),
          label=\textbf{Type 2 System}] {};
% connections not considered in join instruction
\draw [arrow] (A-6) -| node[above] {X} (A-7);
\draw [arrow] (A-6) -| node[above] {Y} (A-10);
%
\draw [arrow] (A-9) -| node[below] {Yes} (L);
\draw [arrow] (L)   |- (A-3);
%
\draw [arrow] (A-12) -| node[below] {No}  (R);
\draw [arrow] (R)    |- (A-3);
%
\draw [arrow] (A-9)  |- node[below] {Yes} (A-13);
\draw [arrow] (A-12) |- node[below] {Yes} (A-13);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you not like to have colored nodes (definitions of nodes I took from some my old answer), please remove their definition from defined styles.